# ¿Cómo crear una animación de entrada en CSS?

Tags: html, css, animación, transicion

Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer una animación de entrada. Tengo un header que se muestra al desplazarse hacia arriba y se oculta al desplazarse hacia abajo. La entrada del elemento (Header) es muy brusca por lo que decidí colocar una transición.

Sin embargo, me conseguir el efecto que tiene el header en la aplicación móvil de "Facebook"  (específicamente la parte del logo de "facebook", la lupa y el icon de messenger). Me refiero que al deslizar hacia arriba se esconde y al dezlizar hacia abajo aparece, pero es gradual, es decir, si se desliza lentamente el "header (logo, icon de lupa e icon de messenger)" va apareciendo gradualmente y viceversa. Incluso si se desliza solo un poco y se mantiene el dedo presionado, el header solo se asoma una pequeña parte.

A continuación coloca las imágenes con su respectiva descripción para poder ilustrar el tema.

En RESUMEN, me gustaría crear el efecto de animación anterior, me gustaría crearlo de preferencia con puro css pero de no ser posible con java Script esta bien.

De antemano gracias por su atención y ayuda.

[image: Aquí se el header en un estado nuero o inicial]

[image: Aquí se ve como el header comienza a ocultar gradualmente () no depnde de un transición común es decir, la animación se puede detener mientras se mantiene pulsando]

[image: Aquí esta el header escondiendo, pero de igual manera, tenia el dedo presionado y el logo no se ocultaba completamente.]

[image: Aquí ya se ve el header oculto]

Comment: Con css se puede hacer perfectamente. Pero no se te puede ayudar sin saber tu código html y css de tu header (si es posible si estás usando js para el scroll de tu header). Edita tu pregunta y agrega los códigos

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde tengo entendido, ese efecto que buscas en la barra de navegación no puede lograrse con solo css pero puedes lograrlo fácilmente con javascript.

Simplemente mantienes tres variables:

- `height` con la que está diseñada tu navBar
- `currenTop` la altura actual de tu barra de navegación
- `currentOpacity` la opacidad actual de tu barra de navegación
- `prevScrollpos` el último valor de scroll

Cuando el usuario haga scroll y se dispare el evento, vas a decrementar o incrementar estas variables de manera proporcional al scroll, obteniendo el efecto suave que buscas que tiene la app de facebook. Te adjunto un ejemplo que puedes ejecutar:

```js
const height = document.querySelector("#navbar").clientHeight;
let currenTop = 0;
let currentOpacity = 1;
let prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

window.onscroll = function () {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    let diff = prevScrollpos - currentScrollPos;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {   // Cuando se hace scroll hacia arriba
        diff = diff < height ? diff : height;
        currenTop = currenTop + diff;
        currenTop = currenTop > 0 ? 0 : currenTop;
        currentOpacity = currentOpacity + diff / height;
    } else { // Cuando se hace scroll hacia abajo
        diff = -diff < height ? -diff : height;
        currenTop = currenTop - diff;
        currenTop = currenTop < -height ? -height : currenTop;
        currentOpacity = currentOpacity - diff / height;
    }

    currentOpacity = currentOpacity < 0 ? 0 : currentOpacity;
    currentOpacity = currentOpacity > 1 ? 1 : currentOpacity;

    let navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    navbar.style.top = currenTop + "px";
    navbar.style.opacity = currentOpacity.toString();
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: #202020;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```